# Django superuser is not created properly

Tags: django, django-models

I have a weird error that I cannot understand. For each user I need to create Customer object:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender = User)
def after_user_is_created(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
   if not instance.is_superuser:
      if created:
         customer = Customer(email = instance.email, status = Status.objects.get(status = "registered"), user = instance)
         customer.save()
```

But with this code when I do initial syncdb to create all my tables and create superuser it's created as is_superuser=False and is_staff=False.

This is my Customer model:

```
class Customer(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length = 120, blank = True)
   middlename = models.CharField(max_length = 120, blank = True)
   surname = models.CharField(max_length = 120, blank = True)
   email = models.EmailField(max_length = 254)
   birthdate = models.DateField(blank = True, null = True)
   status = models.ForeignKey(Status)
   citizenships = models.ManyToManyField(Country, blank = True)
   user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank = True, null = True)
```

I don't understand what is wrong with my code?

Comment: why two email ids actually user table has an emailid

Comment: did u delete all tables and syncdb

Comment: @SundarNataraj I need the second email because this customer table can be used separately. And yes, I deleted the database, recreated it and then ran syncdb.

Comment: For superuser creation follow this code: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/default/#creating-superusers

Comment: @ruddra the same problem

Comment: it is working in my project

Comment: i tried using sqlite. i just deleted previous sqlite and ran syncdb. i got super user with same code of urs

Comment: @SundarNataraj Hmm, if I disable that piece of code, everything works perfectly... Do you think it might be related to some code somewhere else?

Comment: i have used ur signal also it is working..yes there might be wrong with some where else

Comment: ok, thanks for your help. will keep looking...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after switching to django version 1.6.4 from 1.5 my original code started working. Although I'm sure I had version 1.6 before. How I switched to the older version and when I have no idea...